# What does this sentence mean? ‘Two of the bell and mark him, boy, whip-cat tippled already.’

Tags: meaning, literature

> An amused man passing me and pointing to a drunkard struggling to get back on his feet. ‘Two of the bell and mark him, boy,
> whip-cat tippled already.’

From [*How to Stop Time*](http://www.matthaig.com/how-to-stop-time/) by Matt Haig.

Comment: What's the source of the sentence?

Comment: It's only 2 o'clock and he is already as drunk as a skunk.

Comment: it is from a novel by Matt Haigh, named " How to stop time".

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's an attempt at  nautical slang, albeit faux stuff made up by the author. I don't think it's authentic.

'Two of the bell' sounds like the [timekeeping system](https://www.westmarine.com/WestAdvisor/Ships-Bell-Time) used aboard ships in the era of sail. Two bells could be 1, 5  or 9 o'clock.

'mark him, boy'  is easy, it means 'take a look at him.'

'whip-cat tippled'  obviously meaning drunk, I'm guessing it means  so drunk he should be flogged for it.

So the whole thing means: 'take a look at him,young fellow, five in the afternoon(?) and already drunk.'

Comment: As an ex Navy guy, I came here to critique, but this actually seems to be a good interpretation as any. especially the _faux_ part

Comment: "whip the cat" does apparently mean "intoxicated" among many other things (see for example: https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dictionary_of_Slang_and_Unconventional/IAjyQdFwh4UC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22whip-cat%22&pg=PA1329&printsec=frontcover)